# Error in php function session_start()

Tags: php, session

i´m trying to host my site but the following error appeared in php function session_start() does anyone know what it is or how to fix it? Thanks

> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]:
>   open(/var/lib/php-cgi/session/sess_gkmn93lekcnu3ge74efcnlgag7, O_RDWR)
>   failed: No such file or directory (2) in
>   /home/storage/c/e0/01/smokefy1/public_html/system/system.php on line
>   572

Comment: You should give details in **English** for more help

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Can this post be in english?

Comment: There is something wrong with your server. The folder might not have the rights to write and read the sessions that are stored on your server.

Answer (score 1):

The session path was not found on your server or is not acessable. Make sure that the `session directory` is writeable (if you own a VPS you can give the rights by yourself, otherwise you need to contact the support). Try to define your own path by using this script for example:

```
<?php
session_save_path('/home/example.com/sessions');
ini_set('session.gc_probability', 1);
?>
```

There is also an article/guide about this function, you can read it here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the error like this:

```
<?php
  session_save_path('/var/lib/php-cgi/session');
  ini_set('session.save_path',realpath(dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) .'/../session'));
  session_start();
?>
```

thanks you all!

Comment: like what? this does not answer the question. Edit your answer and add the necessary details.